# How would I go about creating a 3D MMORPG Mouse Look?

Tags: scripting, game-engine, 3d-view

How would I go about creating a 3D MMORPG Mouse Look? I have created a 3D Space Rpg that is almost finished with success so far. However, I didn't have a clue, how I would attempt to make a Mouse Look method where if a user right clickes and then holds the right mouse button and moves it around the camera moves around with the mouse. The camera can not move away from your character/ship, it should act as if the character/ship is it's origin and that it rotates all around the origin.

I don't mind coding this with python either. Advice is welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do to get your desired functionally is add the logic bricks pictured below to your camera.
[image: logic bricks]

The most important part is the *Mouse* Actuator, set to *Look* that is what moves the view
The *Always* Sensor is needed to make the mouse look actuator work.
The *Mouse* Sensor set to *Right Button* is what triggers the mouse look actuator.

Answer (score 3):

David's answer *almost* works (sorry Dave, let the pros handle this).

The problem is, as most people will notice, that this orbits the camera around itself, and not, as Blender_Warrior said

> it should act as if the character/ship is it's origin and that it rotates all around the origin.

Now all you need to do is have all the logic from David's answer onto an empty at the position of your player/ship. Move the camera the required and parent it to they empty. YAY! RPG camera as simple as they come.

[image]

**NOTE:** the cubes are just so you have something for your camera to look at so you can see the system working.